# Remote Desktop Connection with Custom Credential Provider

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, remote-desktop, credential-providers

I have developed a custom credential provider using the SampleWrapExistingCredentialProvider from VistaCredentialProviderSamples. The credential provider has a filter implemented that filters all other credential providers and I see just my credential provider at the time of logon. The issue is that if we connect to it using remote desktop connection, the username/password are not passed from windows RDP client to the Credential provider and I have to enter it again when RDP session opens (unlike the behavior with default provider)

I am trying to explore which part of the code handles this scenario that the credential provider accepts the username/password from remote desktop client and does not ask again. Attached is the screenshot of my credential provider after providing successful credentials on the RDP client. After I click this icon of my credential provider, I am shown the credential provider tile that asking again for the username and password. Any help would be highly appreciated on how to receive credentials from RDP client.[image: This is the logon screen that appears after I enter username password on remote desktop connection]

[image: This appears after I select my CP. Username and password not filled up]

I have returned S_OK for CREDUI. My SetUsageScenario is as follows:

```
HRESULT CSampleProvider::SetUsageScenario(
CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO cpus,
DWORD dwFlags
)
{
    HRESULT hr;

// Create the password credential provider and query its interface for an
// ICredentialProvider we can use. Once it's up and running, ask it about the 
// usage scenario being provided.
IUnknown *pUnknown = NULL;
hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_PasswordCredentialProvider, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pUnknown));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pUnknown->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&(_pWrappedProvider)));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = _pWrappedProvider->SetUsageScenario(cpus, dwFlags);
        switch (cpus)
        {
        case CPUS_LOGON:
        case CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION:
        case CPUS_CREDUI:
        {
            hr = S_OK;
            break;
        }
        case CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD:
        default:
            hr = E_INVALIDARG;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    if (_pWrappedProvider != NULL)
    {
        _pWrappedProvider->Release();
        _pWrappedProvider = NULL;
    }
}

return hr;
}
```

Comment: On the RDP client,the credential provider repeatedly asks for th username and password, even if you have successfully entered them?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT No, it does not ask repeatedly on the RDP client. The RDP client successfully authenticates and opens the session, but inside the session, I am left at the logon screen for windows to enter the credentials again

Comment: As I said in the answer, If the user connected with a non-Microsoft credential provider, then you will be prompted on the terminal server to enter credentials again (twice).

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT yes I read it but I have some confusion, I remember I have seen an OTP CP in an organization where the RDP session only asks for OTP after validating credentials from the RDP client and does not ask for username and password again. If the user enters correct OTP, the user is logged in. How come they would be doing this?

Comment: you not need implement `CREDUI` at all for RDP. but you need correct implement `UpdateRemoteCredential` and `SetSerialization` methods. obvivous you do mistake in implementations one(or both) of it. * filter implemented that filters all other credential providers* - you need change the `pcpcsOut->clsidCredentialProvider` to **your** clsid provider in `UpdateRemoteCredential` - this is key point, otherwise `SetSerialization` at all will be not called (becaus eyou disable original clsid) and in `SetSerialization` need restore original `clsidCredentialProvider` before pass this to original

Answer (score 3):

> the username/password are not passed from windows RDP client to the
>   Credential provider and I have to enter it again when RDP session
>   opens (unlike the behavior with default provider)

windows can not by some magic know client username/password, which connecting by rdp.

at begin on client side some credential provider must create `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION` and pass it to server. inside it `clsidCredentialProvider` say which concrete provider collect this serialization.

what server must do with this `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION` ? obvious pass it to some credential provider [`SetSerialization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider-setserialization) method. but for which ? for all ? no. again obvivous only for provider which clsid exactly matches `clsidCredentialProvider` from `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION`.  this provider (if exist and not filtered) must remember this credentional and then when called [`GetCredentialCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider-getcredentialcount) - say that it have dafault credentional (not `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_NO_DEFAULT`) and it usually ready for auto logon attempt with this.

from client side (mstsc) the password provider create serialization. so will be `__uuidof(PasswordCredentialProvider)` or `__uuidof(V1PasswordCredentialProvider)` (if client run on win7) in `clsidCredentialProvider`.

but you disable this providers in self filter. as result you yourself break process.

filter must implement [`UpdateRemoteCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialproviderfilter-updateremotecredential) method. and here **copy and update** passed *pcpcsIn*. most importand part of this - we must **replace** *clsidCredentialProvider* to self CLSID. as result our [`SetSerialization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider-setserialization) method will be called. here we need **restore** original *CLSID* before pass it to wrapped credentional.

also important place - inside [`GetCredentialCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialprovider-getcredentialcount) - first pass it to wrapped credentional and then do `*pbAutoLogonWithDefault = FALSE;` - disable autologon - you can not do this (autologon) if you require additional (OTP ?) information from client.

inside [`UpdateRemoteCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/credentialprovider/nf-credentialprovider-icredentialproviderfilter-updateremotecredential) method we can not modify *pcpcsIn* - if declared as const. so we need write our update credentional to *pcpcsOut*. because system can not know which size is required for `rgbSerialization` - we need **allocate** it yourself. and system then free it. obvivous need use `CoTaskMemAlloc` for allocate `rgbSerialization`.

so - all this can be understanded and without any documentation. however if all this was documented - will be not bad too.

so code for `UpdateRemoteCredential` :

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CSampleProvider::UpdateRemoteCredential( 
    /* [annotation][in] */ 
    _In_  const CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION *pcpcsIn,
    /* [annotation][out] */ 
    _Out_  CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION *pcpcsOut)
{

    if (pcpcsIn->clsidCredentialProvider != __uuidof(PasswordCredentialProvider) && 
        pcpcsIn->clsidCredentialProvider != __uuidof(V1PasswordCredentialProvider))
    {
        // we dont know format of serialization
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }

    ULONG cbSerialization = pcpcsIn->cbSerialization;

    if (pcpcsOut->rgbSerialization = (PBYTE)CoTaskMemAlloc(cbSerialization + sizeof(GUID)))
    {
        memcpy(pcpcsOut->rgbSerialization, pcpcsIn->rgbSerialization, cbSerialization);
        memcpy(pcpcsOut->rgbSerialization + cbSerialization, &pcpcsIn->clsidCredentialProvider, sizeof(GUID));

        pcpcsOut->cbSerialization = cbSerialization + sizeof(GUID);
        pcpcsOut->ulAuthenticationPackage = pcpcsIn->ulAuthenticationPackage;
        pcpcsOut->clsidCredentialProvider = __uuidof(CSampleProvider);

        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
}
```

if we dont know the `clsidCredentialProvider` - simply return `E_UNEXPECTED`

oterwise allocate more (on sizeof(CLSID)) memory and save original `clsidCredentialProvider` in the end

now `SetSerialization`:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CSampleProvider::SetSerialization(
    __in const CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION* pcpcs
    )
{   
    if (pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider == __uuidof(CSampleProvider))
    {
        // can not query WTSIsRemoteSession, small optimization
        _IsRemoteSession = true;

        // we got this via ICredentialProviderFilter::UpdateRemoteCredential
        ULONG cbSerialization = pcpcs->cbSerialization;

        if (cbSerialization >= sizeof(GUID))
        {
            // restore original clsidCredentialProvider
            cbSerialization -= sizeof(GUID);
            memcpy(const_cast<GUID*>(&pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider), pcpcs->rgbSerialization + cbSerialization, sizeof(GUID));
            const_cast<CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION*>(pcpcs)->cbSerialization = cbSerialization;
        }
    }

    return _pWrappedProvider->SetSerialization(pcpcs);
}
```

restore original `clsidCredentialProvider` and fix `cbSerialization`. also because `pcpcs->clsidCredentialProvider == __uuidof(CSampleProvider)` can be set only inside `UpdateRemoteCredential` in my case (i not do `CPUS_CREDUI` on client side for RDP, only for "run as admin") - i just know that this is remote connection and save this information (`_IsRemoteSession = true;`) for not call `WTSIsRemoteSession`

finally `GetCredentialCount`:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE CSampleProvider::GetCredentialCount(
    __out DWORD* pdwCount,
    __out_range(<,*pdwCount) DWORD* pdwDefault,
    __out BOOL* pbAutoLogonWithDefault
    )
{
    HRESULT hr = _pWrappedProvider->GetCredentialCount(pdwCount, pdwDefault, pbAutoLogonWithDefault);

    *pbAutoLogonWithDefault = FALSE;//!!!

    return hr;
}
```

note very important `*pbAutoLogonWithDefault = FALSE;//!!!` line

Comment: Hi. Where is _pWrappedProvider? Do you have code in GitHub?

Comment: @VOLVO - hi. think not hard understand that in concrete code `ICredentialProvider* _pWrappedProvider;` was member of class `CSampleProvider`

Comment: if we implement wrapper not only for password but for multiple providers, code can be next - https://pastebin.com/P8sNLCXc

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentationhttps: [RDC and Custom Credential Providers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2009/07/14/rdc-and-custom-credential-providers/)

> If the user connected with a non-Microsoft credential provider, then
>   you will be prompted on the terminal server to enter credentials again
>   (twice).  If NLA is not enabled, then despite entering using an
>   unsupported credential provider on the client prior to the connection,
>   the user will still be connected.  You will be left at the logon
>   screen, where you can use any credential provider that is supported
>   for local authentication.  There’s no way to avoid the two
>   authentications when using unsupported credential providers.
>
> Having said that, if you have your own credential providers and you
>   try to do a remote desktop connection to a Vista box (having this
>   Credential provider) then you would need to log-in twice. This is an
>   expected behavior and it is by design and there is no legitimate way
>   to avoid it.

Comment: Hmmm confused about this as I have seen some credential provider implementations showing the logon screen with filled up credentials (transferred from the RDP client to windows logon fields)

Comment: @js.hrt You seem to be looking for https://www.rcdevs.com/docs/howtos/openotp_cp/openotp_cp/.

Comment: this is not true that we need **twice** enter credentionals. if we correct enter credentional in mstsc  - we not need reenter it in rdp screen. in case MFA/OTP provider - user by design need also enter valid OTP code, etc. but it not must enter login/password again