# Custom Credential Provider - How to enter password only once over RDP?

Tags: c++, remote-desktop, credential-providers, windows-credential-provider, windows-logon

When using Custom Credential Provider, you must enter the password 2 times.
How to enter a password once and then the OTP code?

I know the documentation says it's not possible, but I've seen a working example.
I have looked at several threads on stackoverflow:

- [Windows Credential Provider - Change User name Label on new Tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75405223/windows-credential-provider-change-user-name-label-on-new-tile?newreg=a9215a7ab30048d4b04df5b6cf6131ab)
- [Remote Desktop Connection with Custom Credential Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317142/remote-desktop-connection-with-custom-credential-provider)

I tried to merge the code from the [second branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317142/remote-desktop-connection-with-custom-credential-provider) with this [code](https://github.com/arcadejust/MultiotpCPV2RDP), but it didn't work.

Comment: why you decide that need enter password 2 times ?! you need implement `UpdateRemoteCredential` and `SetSerialization`

Comment: Yes, I understand. Can you suggest the correct implementation of UpdateRemoteCredential and SetSerialization ?

Comment: you already view it

Comment: OK I understood. When passing data like CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION, I can't login. How to pass data further up the stack? Encrypted password ?